# Line number of last occurrence of a pattern with awk

Tags: awk, tcl

I am new to awk commands. I am trying a way to print the last line number for my pattern match.
I need to integrate that awk command in tcl script..
If someone has answer to it, please let me know.

```
exec awk -v search=$var {$0~search{print NR; exit}} file_name
```

I am using this to print the line number of first occurrence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or, without `awk`:

```
set fh [open file_name]
set lines [split [read $fh] \n]
close $fh
set line_nums [lmap idx [lsearch -all -regexp $lines with] {expr {$idx + 1}}]
set last_line_num [lindex $line_nums end]
```

Answer (score 3):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following, let `file.txt` content be

```
12
15
120
150
1200
1500
```

then

```
awk '$0~"12"{n=NR}END{print n}' file.txt
```

output

```
5
```

Explanation: I am looking for last line containing `12` somewhere, when such line is encountered I set value of variable `n` to number of row (`NR`), when all lines of lines are processed I `print` said value.

(tested in gawk 4.2.1)

Comment: For Tcl: `exec awk -v search=$var {$0 ~ search {n = NR} END {print n}} file_name`

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples and efforts please try following `tac` + `awk` code.

```
tac Input_file | 
awk -v lines=$(wc -l < Input_file) '/12/{print lines-FNR+1;exit}'
```

***Explanation:***

- Using `tac` command to print Input_file's output in reverse order from bottom to top(basically to get very last match very quickly at first and exit from `awk` program, explained later on).
- Sending `tac Input_file` output to `awk` program as an input.
- In `awk` program creating variable named `lines` which has total number of lines of Input_file and in main program checking if line contains `12` then printing `lines-FNR+1` value and using `exit` exiting from program then, by which we need NOT to read whole Input_file.